# Como fazer separate e mutate em r com condicoes?

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma pequena base de dados:

```
1;MD-3101,Balti Botu Pavel 3 ap. 1 SUBSOL
3;MD-3102,Balti str-la Muresanu A. 11
17;MD-3102,Balti Sorocii 46 ap. 2
398;MD-3111,Balti Stefan cel Mare 20    ap. pasaj LIFT
1130;MD-3128,Balti str-la Lvovului 2 ap. 4
1252;MD-3128,Balti str-la Lvovului 1A
2814;MD-3102,Balti Cahulului 44А ap. 20
```

Eu quero separar em 8 colunas com condições e uma mutação em uma determinada coluna.

Eu tenho 8 colunas: Ids,Cod_post,cod_4,tip_str,den_str,nr,ap,extra.

Este é o separado:

```
library(tidyverse)

nord_adresa %>% 
  separate(idsAdresa, into = c("Ids","Adresa"), sep = ";") %>% 
  select(Ids,Adresa) %>% 
  separate(Adresa, into = c("cod_post","cod_x"), sep = ", ") %>% 
  select(Ids,cod_post,cod_x) %>% 
  separate(cod_x, into = c("cod_4","tip_str","den_str","nr","ap","extra"), sep = " ") -> test
```

Este e o mutate:

```
  mutate(den_str = case_when(
    grepl("Stefan cel mare", location) ~ "Stefan cel mare",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )
```

O resultado suposto:

```
ids    cod_post     cod_4   tip_str     den_str           nr    ap        extra

1;     MD-3101,     Balti               Botu Pavel        3     ap. 1     SUBSOL
3;     MD-3102,     Balti   str-la      Muresanu A.       11
17;    MD-3102,     Balti               Sorocii           46    ap. 2
398;   MD-3111,     Balti               Stefan cel Mare   20    ap. pasaj LIFT
1130;  MD-3128,     Balti   str-la      Lvovului          2     ap. 4
1252;  MD-3128,     Balti   str-la      Lvovului          1A
2814;  MD-3102,     Balti               Cahulului         44А   ap. 20
```

```
Então, basicamente
Ids cod_post e cod_4: posso separar com , e ; .
tip_str: Eu só preciso de str-la lá. Portanto, presumo que preciso de um case when ou if?
den_str: É complicado. Eu preciso fazer mutate Botu pavel, Muresanu a. , Stefan cel mare.
nr: meio simples, só aceita números e a letra a.
ap: Só se tiver ap.
extra: basicamente o resto.

É um pouco complicado.
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão é utilizar **regex** para extrair (com a função `str_extract()` do {*stringr*}) os padrões que você deseja.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Primeiro, criando um exemplo reprodutível:

```
df <- 
tibble(idsAdresa = c("1;MD-3101,Balti Botu Pavel 3 ap. 1 SUBSOL",
                     "3;MD-3102,Balti str-la Muresanu A. 11",
                     "17;MD-3102,Balti Sorocii 46 ap. 2",
                     "398;MD-3111,Balti Stefan cel Mare 20    ap. pasaj LIFT",
                     "1130;MD-3128,Balti str-la Lvovului 2 ap. 4",
                     "1252;MD-3128,Balti str-la Lvovului 1A",
                     "2814;MD-3102,Balti Cahulului 44А ap. 20"))


# A tibble: 7 × 1
  idsAdresa                                             
  <chr>                                                 
1 1;MD-3101,Balti Botu Pavel 3 ap. 1 SUBSOL             
2 3;MD-3102,Balti str-la Muresanu A. 11                 
3 17;MD-3102,Balti Sorocii 46 ap. 2                     
4 398;MD-3111,Balti Stefan cel Mare 20    ap. pasaj LIFT
5 1130;MD-3128,Balti str-la Lvovului 2 ap. 4            
6 1252;MD-3128,Balti str-la Lvovului 1A                 
7 2814;MD-3102,Balti Cahulului 44А ap. 20
```

Usando regex para extrair os padrões:

```
df_separado <- 
df %>% 
  mutate(Ids = str_extract(idsAdresa, "^\\d+"),
         Cod_post = str_extract(idsAdresa, ";.*,"),
         cod_4 = str_extract(idsAdresa, "\\w+\\s"),
         tip_str = str_extract(idsAdresa, "str-la"),
         den_str = str_extract(idsAdresa, "\\s[A-Z][a-z]+.*(?<=[a-z]|[A-Z][:punct:])\\s(?=[0-9])"),
         nr = str_extract(idsAdresa, "(?<=\\s)[0-9]+."),
         ap = str_extract(idsAdresa, "ap\\.\\s\\w+"),
         extra = str_extract(idsAdresa, "\\s[A-Z]+$"))


# A tibble: 7 × 9
  idsAdresa      Ids   Cod_p…¹ cod_4 tip_str den_str nr    ap    extra
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1;MD-3101,Bal… 1     ;MD-31… "Bal… NA      " Botu… "3 "  ap. 1 " SU…
2 3;MD-3102,Bal… 3     ;MD-31… "Bal… str-la  " Mure… "11"  NA     NA  
3 17;MD-3102,Ba… 17    ;MD-31… "Bal… NA      " Soro… "46 " ap. 2  NA  
4 398;MD-3111,B… 398   ;MD-31… "Bal… NA      " Stef… "20 " ap. … " LI…
5 1130;MD-3128,… 1130  ;MD-31… "Bal… str-la  " Lvov… "2 "  ap. 4  NA  
6 1252;MD-3128,… 1252  ;MD-31… "Bal… str-la  " Lvov… "1A"  NA     NA  
7 2814;MD-3102,… 2814  ;MD-31… "Bal… NA      " Cahu… "44А" ap. …  NA  
# … with abbreviated variable name ¹​Cod_post
```

Explicação das regex

- `Ids = str_extract(idsAdresa, "^\\d+")`: um ou mais dígitos (`\\d+`) no início da string (`^`);
- `Cod_post = str_extract(idsAdresa, ";.*,")`: ponto-e-vírgula (`;`) seguido de qualquer coisa (`.*`) seguido de uma vírgula (`,`)
- `cod_4 = str_extract(idsAdresa, "\\w+\\s")`: uma palavra (`\\w+`) seguida de um espaço (`\\s`)
- `tip_str = str_extract(idsAdresa, "str-la")`: o padrão de letras `str-la` (se não existir, será atribuído `NA`)
- `den_str = str_extract(idsAdresa, "\\s[A-Z][a-z]+.*(?<=[a-z]|[A-Z][:punct:])\\s(?=[0-9])")`:

  - um espaço em branco (`\\s`) seguido de...
  - qualquer palavra que comece com uma letra maiúscula seguida por uma ou mais letras minúsculas (`[A-Z][a-z]+`) seguida de...
  - qualquer coisa (`.*`) seguida de...
  - um espaço em branco (`\\s`). O detalhe é que não é qualquer espaço em branco. Tem que ser um espaço em branco que:

    - seja precedido (`?<=`) por um uma letra minúscula (`a-z`) ou (`|`) por uma letra maíscula (`A-Z`) seguido por qualquer tipo de pontuação (`[:punct:]`): isso tudo fica encapsulado por parênteses, o que equivale ao seguinte trecho: `(?<=[a-z]|[A-Z][:punct:])\\s`;
    - e ao mesmo tempo seja seguido por (`?=`) um número (`[0-9]`), o que, encapsulado pelos parênteses equivale ao seguinte trecho: `\\s(?=[0-9])`
    - como espaço em questão precisa atender simultaneamente ao que vem antes e ao que vem depois, a expressão completa fica: `(?<=[a-z]|[A-Z][:punct:])\\s(?=[0-9])`. Observe o `\\s` na regex e veja o que vem encapsulado pelos parênteses antes e depois dele.
- `nr = str_extract(idsAdresa, "(?<=\\s)[0-9]+.")`: um ou mais números (`[0-9]+`) simultaneamente precedido por um espaço (`(?<=\\s)`) e seguido por qualquer caracter (`.`)
- `ap = str_extract(idsAdresa, "ap\\.\\s\\w+")`: o padrão de letras `ap` seguido por um ponto (`\\.`) seguido por um espaço (`\\s`) seguido por uma palavra (`\\w+`). O detalhe é que como essa variável está como `character`, ela considera um número como palavra. Assim, é possível capturar tanto os números, como as palavras de fato (como no caso de "pasaj")
- `extra = str_extract(idsAdresa, "\\s[A-Z]+$")`: um espaço (`\\s`) seguido de uma palavra composta apenas por letras maísculas (`[A-Z]+`) ancorada ao final da string (`$`)

Uma vez feita a separação, é preciso limpar o dataset:

```
df_limpo <- 
  df_separado %>% 
  mutate(Ids = as.numeric(Ids),
         Cod_post = str_remove_all(Cod_post, "\\;|\\,"),
         cod_4 = str_trim(cod_4),
         den_str = str_trim(den_str),
         nr = str_trim(nr),
         extra = str_trim(extra))

# A tibble: 7 × 9
  idsAdresa        Ids Cod_p…¹ cod_4 tip_str den_str nr    ap    extra
  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1;MD-3101,Bal…     1 MD-3101 Balti NA      Botu P… 3     ap. 1 SUBS…
2 3;MD-3102,Bal…     3 MD-3102 Balti str-la  Muresa… 11    NA    NA   
3 17;MD-3102,Ba…    17 MD-3102 Balti NA      Sorocii 46    ap. 2 NA   
4 398;MD-3111,B…   398 MD-3111 Balti NA      Stefan… 20    ap. … LIFT 
5 1130;MD-3128,…  1130 MD-3128 Balti str-la  Lvovul… 2     ap. 4 NA   
6 1252;MD-3128,…  1252 MD-3128 Balti str-la  Lvovul… 1A    NA    NA   
7 2814;MD-3102,…  2814 MD-3102 Balti NA      Cahulu… 44А   ap. … NA
```

Explicação:

- `Ids = as.numeric(Ids)`: converte os Ids para o formato numérico;
- `Cod_post = str_remove_all(Cod_post, "\\;|\\,")`: remove os ponto-e-virgulas e as vírgulas
- `cod_4 = str_trim(cod_4)`: elimina os espaços no começo e/ou final da string
- `den_str = str_trim(den_str)`: idem
- `nr = str_trim(nr)`: idem
- `extra = str_trim(extra)`: idem

Por fim, bastar retirar a coluna original:

```
df_limpo %>% 
  select(-idsAdresa)

# A tibble: 7 × 8
    Ids Cod_post cod_4 tip_str den_str         nr    ap        extra 
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>           <chr> <chr>     <chr> 
1     1 MD-3101  Balti NA      Botu Pavel      3     ap. 1     SUBSOL
2     3 MD-3102  Balti str-la  Muresanu A.     11    NA        NA    
3    17 MD-3102  Balti NA      Sorocii         46    ap. 2     NA    
4   398 MD-3111  Balti NA      Stefan cel Mare 20    ap. pasaj LIFT  
5  1130 MD-3128  Balti str-la  Lvovului        2     ap. 4     NA    
6  1252 MD-3128  Balti str-la  Lvovului        1A    NA        NA    
7  2814 MD-3102  Balti NA      Cahulului       44А   ap. 20    NA
```